# Contar registros iguais com SELECT DISTINCT e COUNT

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

Como faço pra contar os resultados iguais e adicionar a quantidade na frente?

Por exemplo:

Atualmente os registros da minha tabela está assim:

```
Id  | Nome 
------------
0   | Teste
1   | Teste
2   | Teste
```

Quero dar um `DISTINCT` nelas e deixá-las assim:

```
Id  | Nome 
------------
0   | Teste(3)
```

## SQLFIDDLE para testes

 Estou usando `MySql`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode tentar utilizar a seguinte expressão sql:

```
select  distinct id, CONCAT(nome, "(",count(id),")") as Nome from teste group by nome;
```

Comment: A mesma funciona para `MySql`? Que foi a `tag` que inseri na pergunta.

Comment: sim funciona @Exception parabens Pedro

Comment: @Exception funciona sim testei aqui no MySQL Workbench

Comment: @Otto obrigado^^

Comment: Nem precisa usar DISTINCT...

Comment: @KaduAmaral sim mas ele pediu... Contar registros iguais com SELECT DISTINCT e COUNT

Comment: @PedroRangel Testei aqui e deu certo. Valeo!

Answer (score 4):

Veja se isto te ajuda:

```
select COUNT(distinct Nome) from @TableTeste
```

Comment: Não pois só contou as `rows`, não colocou o `Teste(3)` por exemplo. Deveria contar as `rows` e colocar na frente do resultado.

Comment: sim sim eu percebi, havia esquecido de colocar o concat como o amigo @Pedro Rangel

Answer (score 3):

Busquei a mesma ajuda e essa foi uma solução que funcionou.

```
SELECT DISTINCT campo1
               ,campo2
               ,campo3
               ,campo4
               ,campo5
               ,campo6
               ,campo7
               ,COUNT(*) AS quantidade
  FROM tabela_a
 GROUP BY campo1
         ,campo2
         ,campo3
         ,campo4
         ,campo5
         ,campo6
         ,campo7
 ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

<sub>Creditos:
Luan Moreno [SQL Soul]|| Especialista SQL Server || MCTS SQL Server Admin e Dev @luansql</sub>

Comment: Alguém explica os votos negativos? O princípio está certo, só não está mastigada para o problema específico. A query não está explicada em detalhes, mas a mesma coisa com a pergunta aceita, que não está com negativos.

Answer (score 2):

No SQLFIDDLE Teste:

```
create table algo(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  nome varchar(10) not null,
  primary key(id));


  insert into algo (id, nome) values (0,'Teste');
  insert into algo (nome) values (1,'Teste');
  insert into algo (nome) values (2,'Teste');

  select distinct concat(nome,'(',(select count(id) from algo),')') as nome from algo;
  select distinct concat(nome,'(',count(id),')') as nome from algo;
  select distinct sum(id-id) as id, concat(nome,'(',count(id),')') as nome from algo group by nome;
```

Answer (score -2):

acho que esse pode te ajudar!!

```
SELECT   Nome,
         COUNT(Nome) AS Qtd
FROM  Clientes
GROUP BY Nome
ORDER BY COUNT(Nome) DESC
```